# Null against empty in Java

Tags: java

I have a JSON file. Now, I query it based on keyword, and save it into array.
The problem is the value could be empty, null, or string. 
So my codes have exception:

> NumberFormatException: for input string: "null"
>   at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)

Here is my codes:

```
for(int i=0, size=jsonStr.length; i<size; i++){

    if(jsonStr[i]==null){
        System.out.println("It's null");
    }else if(jsonStr[i].isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("It is empty!");
    }else if(Float.parseFloat(jsonStr[i])>=0){
        result[j]=jsonStr[i];
    }else{
      collect[j]=jsonStr[i];
    }


}
```

May I ask how to avoid it? the value in jsonStr could be "", null, or string(can be converted to float).

Thank you

Comment: What json parser are you using?

Comment: It looks like the string is literally `"null"`, not `null`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I use getJSONArray from jsonObject. and getJSONArray from JSONObject.

Comment: @Eric Not at all, if you consider that formatting a null element results in a `NullPointerException` rather than a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @Gamb Right! It is just String:"Null" Thank you

Comment: @Eric Thank you, I made mistake, it is string:"null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Float.parseFloat("null")` will throws `NumberFormatException: for input string: "null"`.

So, your json looks like `{"str" : "null"}` instead of `{"str" : null}`.
For this case you should use `"null".equals(...)`

```
if(jsonStr[i]==null || "null".equals(jsonStr[i]))
{
   System.out.println("It's null");
}
else if(jsonStr[i].isEmpty())
{
   System.out.println("It is empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an exception because you are comparing an int with null.

you must check object type first.

if (jsonStr instanceof Integer)

Comment: In case of compairing `int` with `null` `NullPointerException` will be thrown